# Why appium don't close appium after each test?

Tags: javascript, cucumber, appium, webdriver-io

I'm working on a Appium project using JS(WebDriverIO + Cucumber) and I've tried all possibilities which I could imagine.

That's my capabilities:

```
capabilities: [
        {
            platformName: 'Android',
            "appium:deviceName": "Pixel 2 API 30",
            "appium:fullReset": true,
            "appium:noReset": false,
            "appium:autoLaunch": true,
            "appium:automationName":"UIAutomator2",
            "appium:autoGrantPermissions": true,
"appium:app":app_path
        }
```

I've been tried change all reset options without success. Just describing what's happening step-by-step:

- test case 1 run successfuly ✅
- app don't close automatically
- test case 2 fail because app still with another screen opened.

Anybody have any idea?

I was using appium 2.0.0-beta.46 but change to lastest stable, 1.22.3.

Tried change noReset and fullReset caps.

I'm expecting that appium clear, uninstall and install app again after each test case.

Answer (score 0):

Hie man, I think the solution would be for you to remove:

```
"appium:autoLaunch": true,
```

That capability actually stops appium from reLaunching/reopening an app at the start of a test run. Note that its different to "NoReset" because no reset clears your app's cache but autoLaunch only reopens the app instead of resuming on the same page your last test ended.

One more thing, try to use the same Port when running your tests.port 4723 is the best one for me